# How to show that (2n-1)(2n-3)!! = (2n-1)!!

Tags: proof-verification, factorial

I need to show that $(2n-1)(2n-3)!! = (2n-1)!!$ in order to validate an expression for a proof. Wolfram Alpha tells me that this is true for $Re(n)=-1/2$ 
I don't know enough to know how to proceed in showing this.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: With x!!, do you mean (x!)!  i.e. ! applied twice?

Comment: No, I mean the doublke factorial. I'm not sure how I would proceed with an induction proof here.

Comment: See this link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282n-1%29%282n-3%29%21%21%3D%282n-1%29%21%21 It shows that this is true for Re(n) > -1/2

Comment: What is your definition of $n!!$?

Comment: $(2n-1)((2n-3)!!) = (2n-1)!!$ comes from the definition of double factorial

Comment: Can I just write that by definition $(2n−1)((2n−3)!!)=(2n−1)!!$ is true, in my proof? or is there a more clear statement I can use? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of double factorial,

$(2n-1)!! = (2n-1).(2n-3).(2n-5) \dots 1 = (2n-1).((2n-3)!!)$

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.